# Two labels alignment and its constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, constraints

I have 2 labels: the description label (w/ red background) and the results label (gray text)

How do i set constraints for this example in order to have the results label with the size of its content and the description label until the results leadingAnchor? (like i have in the second row)

[image: example]

Objective C

```
[self.customTextLabel.trailingAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor:self.counterLabel.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[self.counterLabel.widthAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToConstant:0].active = YES;
```

swift

```
titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: counterLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
counterLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0).isActive = true
```

I have a solution that i think it's ugly.

```
self.counterLabelWidthConstraint = [self.counterLabel.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:0];
self.counterLabelWidthConstraint.active = YES;
```

And then after i set the text:

```
self.counterLabelWidthConstraint.constant = [self.counterLabel sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, self.counterLabel.height)].width;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this with auto layout is by using the `contentCompressionResistancePriority` of the 2 labels. Set the pririty to `NSLayoutPriorityRequired` for the second label and something lower like `NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow` for the first label. Then, as long as the 2 labels have proper constraints anchoring them to their superview and each other, the first label should compress while the second label should not.

Comment: Awww come on- but I answered 50 seconds before Dima! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You just need to increase the horizontal compression resistance of the right/gray label to be higher than that of the left/red label. This tells the visual layout that, in the event that there is not enough space for both labels, the one on the left will be compressed before shrinking the label on the right. 750 is the default for all views, so just increase the right/gray label's horizontal compression resistance to 751 and you should be good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5** programatically:

`<#label#>.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)`

Labels with this property will not compress horizontally.

Answer (score -1):

You can set constraints for in storyboard itself. Select Label 1 (red back ground) and label's superview set widths are equal constraint. Select Label 1 and double tap on its width constraint, from the resultant window, you could see Lable 1 width equal to superview with value constant as '1'. change '1' to 0.7 or whichever the percentage you want.

Comment: i don't want percentage. it depends on the size of the results content. Thanks anyway